# UIViewController Custom Transition gives wrong type of the "from" ViewController from TransitionContext

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiviewcontroller, uiviewanimationtransition

I am making a custom transition for ViewController Presentation. What I have encountered is the **fromViewController** in the TransitionContext has the wrong type of class. It should be **UICustomXXXXXViewController** whereas it is shown as **UINavigationController**. The weird thing is that the **toViewController** does give back correct type.

I have a PresentationStrategy class:

```
class PresentationStrategy: NSObject {
    private let animator: BaseTransitioningAnimator

    init(animator: BaseTransitioningAnimator) {
        self.animator = animator
    }

    static var resultDetailBouncyExpand = PresentationStrategy(animator: BouncyExpandAnimator(duration: 0.9))

}

extension PresentationStrategy: UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {
    func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController,
                             presenting: UIViewController,
                             source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        animator.transitionType = .present
        return animator
    }

    func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        animator.transitionType = .dismiss
        return animator
    }
}
```

and in the animator's animationTransition function I simply call

```
let fromViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from)!
```

Because I need to access something in the presenting view controller so I need to cast it to the specific class. But when It's shown to be not the type of the class that is presenting it.

```
Printing description of fromViewController:
<UINavigationController: 0x7fac0580e000>
```

And here's how I present it

```
presentedVC.transitioningDelegate = PresentationStrategy.resultDetailBouncyExpand
        presentingVC.present(presentedVC, animated: true)
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @DarkAgeOutlaw yeah you need to get the first vc of the navigation controller I think. Figured this out a while ago.